# My flutter code got red line and couldn't do debuging

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52ViT.png)

I got red lines under my code
and cannot do debug anything.
red line and don't work
pls help me

I checked flutter doctor, and everything was fine.
What am I have to do than?
Im so confusing. let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a new project...